# Finding solution off pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$z=z(x,y)$,$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=z_x$,$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=z_y$ and $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x 
\partial y }=z_{xy}$ and go on like that find the solution of
$$6z_{xxxxxyy}-3z_{xxxxxx}+2z_{xxxyyy}-z_{xxxxy}=0$$==$$6\frac{\partial^7 z}{\partial x^5 \partial y^2}-3\frac{\partial^6 z}{\partial x^6}+2 
\frac{\partial^6 z}{\partial x^3 \partial y^3}-\frac{\partial^5 z}{\partial x^4\partial y}=0$$ how can I solve this I tried operator methods but $D_x^3.(3D_x^2+D_y).(2D_y^2-D_x)).z=0$ I couldn't solve

Comment: You can split $z$ into three solutions $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}$ so that $$z = z_{1} + z_{2} + z_{3}$$ Applying the derivative operator to both sides, if you can find the solutions for the $z_{i}$ such that the first solution $z_{1}$ solves $D_{x}^{3} z_{1} = 0$, the second solution $z_{2}$ solves $(3D_{x}^{2} + D_{y}) z_{2} = 0$, and the final solution $z_{3}$ solves $(2 D_{y}^{2} - D_{x}) z_{3} = 0$ then you are done.

Comment: How can I solve $(3D_x^2+D_y).z_2=0$ I couldn't find any example